# Angular 7 is calling asp.net webapi twice

Tags: angular

I am having performance issues with my angular 7 application. I am using angular 7 as client and c#. asp.net.webapi as the server code. I have noticed that there are two calls made to the webapi endpoint and not sure why ? A another thing that I have noticed is that it initially shows 7 seconds and later 1.7 or 1.8 sec. Why does it do that

Screenshot 1 of Network tab

[image]

Screenshot2 of Network tab

[image]

The pic shown in the screenshot 2 is the same for the first call as well.  I have also seen the call type is `xhr`. What does that mean

Angular Component service call

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { TermsService } from '../services/terms.service';
import { FundClassesComponent } from './fundClasses/fundClasses.component';
import { TermsStateService } from '../services/terms-state.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FundStrategySelectorComponent } from '../directives/managerStrategySelector';
import { LegalFundClassesComponent } from './fundClasses/legalFundClasses.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'mgr-terms',
    templateUrl: 'terms.component.html'
})


export class TermsComponent implements OnInit {

    private Error: string;
    public TermDetails: any;
    private _ManagerStrategyId: number;
    FilteredClasses: any;
    OriginalList: any;
    Funds: any;
    FundClassType: any;
    FirmFunds: any;
    FundTerms: any;
    recordCount: any;
    Loading: boolean;
    StrategyName: any;
    public get ManagerStrategyId(): number {
        return this._ManagerStrategyId;
    }

    @ViewChild('combo')
    combo: FundStrategySelectorComponent;

    @ViewChild(FundClassesComponent)
    fundClassesComponent: FundClassesComponent;


    @ViewChild(FundClassesComponent)
    legalFundClassesComponent: LegalFundClassesComponent;

    @Input()
    public set ManagerStrategyId(value: number) {
        this._ManagerStrategyId = value;
    }
    FundClasses: any;
    LegalFundClasses: any;
    originalFundClasses: any;
    constructor(private termsService: TermsService, private termsStateService: TermsStateService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, ) {

        this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
                this.ManagerStrategyId = params['id'];
                this.ngOnInit();
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.init();
    }

    init() {
        //this.Loading = true;
        this.getTermsDetails();
    }

    public getFundInvestedDetails(isInvested: boolean) {
        if (isInvested) {
            this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
        } else {
            this.FundClasses = this.OriginalList.FundClassViewModel;
        }
    }

    public getLegalFundInvestedDetails(isInvested: boolean) {
        if (isInvested) {
            this.LegalFundClasses = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel;

        } else {
            this.LegalFundClasses = this.OriginalList.LegalFundClassViewModel;
        }
    }

    public reset() {
        this.combo.reset();
    }

    public goHome() {
        this.router.navigate([`/home`]);
    }
    public getTermsDetails() {
        if (this.ManagerStrategyId != null) {
            if (this.fundClassesComponent && !this.fundClassesComponent.Load ||
                this.legalFundClassesComponent && this.legalFundClassesComponent.Load) {
                this.Loading = false;
            } else {
                this.Loading = true;
            }

            this.termsService.getTermsDetails(this.ManagerStrategyId).subscribe((data: any) => {
                this.TermDetails = data;
                this.OriginalList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

                if (this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel) {
                    this.FundClasses = this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel;
                }

                if (this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel) {
                    this.LegalFundClasses = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel;
                }
                if (this.TermDetails.FundTermsViewModel) {
                    this.FundTerms = this.TermDetails.FundTermsViewModel;
                }
                if (this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel) {
                    if (this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.Funds) {
                        this.Funds = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.Funds;
                    }
                    if (this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.FundClassType) {
                        this.FundClassType = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.FundClassType;
                    }
                    if (this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.FirmFunds) {
                        this.FirmFunds = this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.FirmFunds;
                    }
                }
                this.termsStateService.CanEdit = this.TermDetails.CanEdit;
                this.StrategyName = this.TermDetails.FundStrategyName;
                this.termsStateService.CanEditManagerStrategy = this.TermDetails.CanEditManagerStrategy;

                if (this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel && this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel) { 
                this.TermDetails.FundClassViewModel.FundDetailsViewModel.forEach(funDetail => {
                    funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel = funDetail.FundClassDetailsViewModel
                        .reduce((prev, next) => prev = prev.concat(next), [])
                        .filter(obj => obj.InvestedAmount !== null);
                });
            }

            if( this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel &&  this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.AllTerms) {
                this.TermDetails.LegalFundClassViewModel.AllTerms = this.TermDetails
                    .LegalFundClassViewModel
                    .AllTerms.filter(obj => {
                        for (var prop in obj) {
                            return obj[prop] ? obj[prop].InvestmentStatusId === 1 : null;
                        }
                    });
                }

                this.Loading = false;

            });

        }
    }
}
```

Angular Service

```
@Injectable()
export class TermsService {
        _searchFilter: string;
        creds = { withCredentials: true }

        constructor(private mgr360CommonService: Manager360CommonService) { }


        getTermsDetails(managerStrategyId: number) {
                return this.mgr360CommonService.httpGet('/api/terms/details/' + managerStrategyId);
              }
  }
```

Angular shared Service

```
const httpPostOptions = {

    headers:
        new HttpHeaders(
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            }),
    withCredentials: true,
};

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Manager360CommonService {

    webApiLocation = this.getApiLocation();

    private getApiLocation() {
        const port = location.port ? ':56888' : '';
        return location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + port;
    }

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }



    httpGet(url: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get( this.webApiLocation + url, httpPostOptions)
            .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
                return response;
            }), catchError(error => {
                this.onError(error);
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Can't see a problem here. Maybe you can post the whole code of your component.

Comment: Can you check if the first request is of type OPTIONS? If yes. This is normal. The browser execute an OPTIONS request first.

Comment: It is . Why is options request needed ?

Comment: Also could you tell me why initially the request on the network tab shows 7 seconds and then updates to less than 2 seconds .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1st call must be of type **OPTION**. Check the Request method in that.

`OPTIONS` requests are pre-flight requests in Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS).

They are necessary while making requests across different origins in specific situations.

For more info, visit this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)

Comment: Also could you tell me why initially the request on the network tab shows 7 seconds and then updates to less than 2 seconds .

Comment: To understand more about request timings, read https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/understanding-resource-timing

Comment: If you see the port that I have mentioned it is 56888 in service code. I am accessing the application from the same port. Then how is that cross origin? In my development environment, we have the asp.net MVC application and angular application running as one unit. the MVc app uses port 56888 while angular app is using port 4200. Do you think is this the reason . Also when they are deployed on server as one unit within IIS then this problem may not occur. Do you think my thinking is right

Comment: Angular is running in 4200 and API in 56888. Diffrent ports, hence Cross-Origin. You also need to handle CORS in your backend

Comment: Handle ? How is that ? Will that improve performance. Also when deployed on the server on IIS, that would eliminate cors

Comment: This is not about performance. Are you using .NET Framework 4.6 or Core? I will share link on how to handle CORS based on that, You can also study a litthe about this.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.6

Comment: Read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: If you don't have any more doubt, would you please accept this answer as correct